# Auto post back on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, postback, scriptmanager

I need to autopostback my page on the first load, and i need to wait the entire page have finish loading before post back the page.

I use in the page load

```
if (!IsPageWasPostBack)
      {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "forcePostBack", "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(postBackLoading);function postBackLoading(){__doPostBack('" + this.Page.ClientID + "','');}", true);
      }
```

IsPageWasPostBack is a viewstate variable.

When i put

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest
```

my page dont post back. If i remove it the page post back succesfully but to fast.

I dont want use timer to call back my post back.

Any idea ?

Comment: Something doesn't seem like it's written very effectively if you *need* to do a postback on the first page load.  That's just very uncommon behavior -- why can't you execute what needs to happen on the post back when the page first loads?

Comment: Because i have an two iframe communicated together, and the first iframe send information in hidden of the second iframe client side, but i need this information server side, so i need to post back my second frame after the first loading to get the information in the hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use jquery and use $(document).ready($("#myform).submit();) 
or you could wait for the ready then have a timer in your javascript just to wait a few extra seconds.

Comment: I accept this answer but, i do it another way because my context is different, but this way are maybe a good way.

Answer (score 0):

What about waiting a few seconds?

```
$(document).ready(
   setTimeout('$("#myform).submit()',2000);
) ;
```

Comment: I try to find another method than use timeout, i dont think this solutions is clean, beacause the result could not be the same on different computer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [LoadComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcomplete.aspx) event instead of the Load event?